Oracle apex importing excel with date column
I have an excel file which correctly imports all data into an apex table except my date type column, that one I have set up with the TO_DATE(col008, 'dd.mm.yyyy') which has before worked in previous apex forms I created but now it throws an ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected error which I do not understand. I have tested the other columns by setting this col008 to null and they are all uploaded correctly.
I do not know if the issue is with my excel that every time i try to write a date and use general for the format it converts it to a number or if the issue is in the sql.
Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated
Thank you
